# Force Moment.js format() to ignore daylight savings time JS

Tags: javascript, momentjs, dst

I am currently in PST at `-07:00` from UTC.

If I do this: `moment().format('Z')` I correctly get `-07:00`.
Is there a way to (simply) force moment.format() to ignore daylight savings time, (and in my case give me `-08:00`)?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're asking. I think you want to use [`utcOffset`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc-offset/) (`moment().utcOffset("-08:00").format("Z") === "-08:00"`), but it sounds like you might want it generic to include all timezones.

Comment: Correct. I would like it to be generic to include all zones.

Comment: Sounds like you want something more like Moment Timezone: https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/zone-object/

Answer (score 5):

The following code will do what you asked:

```js
// First we need to get the standard offset for the current time zone.
// Since summer and winter are at opposite times in northern and summer hemispheres,
// we will take a Jan 1st and Jul 1st offset.  The standard offset is the smaller value
// (If DST is applicable, these will differ and the daylight offset is the larger value.)
var janOffset = moment({M:0, d:1}).utcOffset();
var julOffset = moment({M:6, d:1}).utcOffset();
var stdOffset = Math.min(janOffset, julOffset);

// Then we can make a Moment object with the current time at that fixed offset
var nowWithoutDST = moment().utcOffset(stdOffset);

// Finally, we can format the object however we like. 'Z' provides the offset as a string.
var offsetAsString = nowWithoutDST.format('Z');
```

***However:*** You should probably ask yourself *why* you want to do this.  In the vast majority of cases, ignoring DST when it is actually in effect is an error.  Your users don't have a choice of whether or not they use DST.  If it's applicable in their local time zone, then your code needs to also take it into account.  Don't try to defeat it.

On the other hand, if you're simply displaying what the time or offset would be without DST for informational purposes, that is probably acceptable.

Comment: We would want to do this for a data feed that explicitly ignores DST.

Comment: Quite handy. I note that internally, moment uses June (i.e., `M:5`) as their second test in `isDaylightSavingTime()`, rather than `M:6`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to get the offset from a non-DST timestamp and then munge the strings.

Assuming a date of some kind, this should get you a string which is date + DST-ignorant-offset:

```
function _noDST(noDST, dateStr){
    var beginningOfTimeNoDST = moment(noDST); // whatever target you know has no DST
    var d = moment(dateStr);
    var noOffset = d.format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss');
    var offset = beginningOfTimeNoDST.format('Z');
    return [noOffset, offset].join("");
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't a sound approach.  Some time zones *were* on DST on 1970-01-01.  Or at least, we may consider that offset DST by today's rules.  Example: [London, England](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/uk/london?year=1970) was UTC+1 for all of 1970.

Comment: A downvote is warranted when the answer is not useful, as stated in the mouseover tooltip of the downvote button.  In this case, the answer is still not useful.  Again, you're assuming that every time zone that might have DST would not have it on January 1st.  That excludes locations in the southern hemisphere, such as Brazil.

Comment: Thumbs up for the help on the mouseover tooltip on the downvote button. Guess I don't use it enough to know that.

Comment: Thanks for trying.  In general, you were on the right track with trying to figure out the offset for a date that doesn't have DST in the current time zone.  Just, your implementation is off.  I do appreciate your effort though! :)

Comment: On the downvote - please don't take it personally.  Down-voting has a purpose.  You may want to review: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121350/ive-just-been-downvoted-how-should-i-react.  Thanks.

Answer (score -3):

This should subtract an hour during DST, if that’s what you want.

```
moment().subtract(moment().isDST() ? 1 : 0, ‘hours’).format('Z')
```

Update: As noted in comments this only works in cases where you know the timezone is 1 hour ahead during DST.

Comment: Some time zones don't differ by a single, whole hour during DST.

Comment: This also does not seem to work:
`console.log(moment().subtract( 1 , 'hours').format('Z')); // -07:00`
`console.log(moment().subtract( 0 , 'hours').format('Z')); // -07:00`

Comment: Adding or subtracting an offset is never the right way to adjust for time zones.  That simply gives you a different moment in time.  (An hour earlier, in this case.)